# How do I use a variable in a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am looping thru an array of words and want to use Ben Alman's replace text library(http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/) to find the match and make them turn red. This is what i have now, but I have little knowledge of regular expression and would like some help on how to create a regular expression from the array of words.

```
  var words = ['word1', 'word2','word3','word4','word5'];
  function colorize( str ) {
      return '<span class="red">' + str + '<\/span>';
    };

    $.each(words, function(i, val){
         var re = new RegExp("not sure what goes here","g"); 
        $('#editor').replaceText(re,colorize );
    });
```

Try this and it doesn't work:

```
$.each(words, function(i, val){
       var re = new RegExp("/\b" + val + "\b","gi");
      $('#editor').replaceText(re,colorize );
    });
```

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Are you sure this library is still in use? Also, why do you absolutely need a regexp here? Can't you just use the native `replace()` function?

Comment: Just updated the link. I would love not to use regexp but I am not sure how to handle lowercase and uppercase instances..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you don't even need the loop. you can do:

```
var words = [...];
function colorize( str ) { ... }

var re = new RegExp("\\b(" + words.join("|") + ")\\b","gi");
$('#editor').replaceText(re,colorize );
```

(notice the `i` in the second parameter as well, this gives the case insensitivity that you mentioned in your comment)

Comment: this doesn't work...

Comment: you're right, I had the wrong format for the RegExp constructor and forgot to double-escape my `\b`s. give the edited code a try

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, I do believe all you need to do is this:

```
$("#editor").replaceText(/oldText/gi, "newText");
```